# Need MySQL Performance Analyzer API

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, analyzer, workbench

Is there some API for java that scrapes me db performance metrics. e.g query execution time, db storage usage etc. I want to create a monitoring tool for MYSQL database.

Comment: "Storage usage" is probably useless since most storage is shared.  Execution time can be found in the slowlog.

Comment: I want to also find out how many queries are in queue. Read and write latency, io delay, query execution time. Stuff like this.

Comment: Again, the slowlog has some of that.  There is no "queue"; essentially a query is started as soon it is encountered.